# PHP/database table loop - display only 15 rows at time

Tags: php, sql, loops, mysqli

I have a database I'm trying to display for edit through PHP. On the main page I want to show only the first 15 rows of the table then have the user click to generate more table rows.

```
<?php 
include('../config.php'); 
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT uid, title, description, tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.* FROM tblFacilityHrs LEFT JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes ON tblFacilityHrs.uid = tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid ORDER BY tblFacilityHrs.title") or die($mysqli->error);
    while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        extract ($row);
        echo "<tr>";  
            echo "<td> {$id} </td>";  //hide when finished
            echo "<td> {$title} </td>"; 
            echo "<td> {$description} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$startEventDate} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$endEventDate} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$startTime} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$endTime} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$days} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$recurrence} </td>";
            echo "<td> {$finalDate} </td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a class=\"buttons\" href=edit.php?id={$id}&uid={$uid}>Edit</a><span class='icon'></span></a>
";
            echo " / ";
            echo "<a class=\"buttons\" href='javascript: Confirm()'>Delete</a>";
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</div>"; 
    } 

echo "</table>";

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: @에이바, Are you wanting to display 15 records per page i.e. if there are 100 records, then four pages with 15 records on each?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for Pagination, this can be done through mysql **LIMIT**

Something like that

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT uid, title, description, tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.* FROM tblFacilityHrs LEFT JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes ON tblFacilityHrs.uid = tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid ORDER BY tblFacilityHrs.title LIMIT 15, $page ")
```

Where $page is for offset

Here are few tutorial for creating custom pagination

[Pagination of MySQL Query Results](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm)

[Pagination - what it is and how to do it](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/pagination.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/limit-optimization.html):

```
"SELECT uid, title, description, tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.* FROM tblFacilityHrs LEFT JOIN tblFacilityHrsDateTimes ON tblFacilityHrs.uid = tblFacilityHrsDateTimes.owner_uid ORDER BY tblFacilityHrs.title LIMIT 15"
```

Comment: You would indicate your start point, in theis case 15, and then specify how many more rows to get, which would be 15: `limit 15, 15`. For the next set: `limit 30, 15`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `limit` syntax [in this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html). `select * from table limit 0,15` will return 15 rows starting with offset 0 (the first row). For the second page you'd use `limit 15, 15` to get rows 16-30, then `limit 30,15` and so on.

Comment: Would I have to make a whole new page for this?

Comment: No, just reload the page and pass the new offset as a variable. When the user first visits the page, `$offset` defaults to zero. When they click the "next page" button, it sends a request that includes a form field like `<input type="hidden" name="offset" value="{$offset+15}">`. When the page reloads and runs the query again, it will use 15 as the new offset, and when they hit "next" again it will use 30, and so on. (you need to actually write your query to use `$offset` as the first argument for `LIMIT`).

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at Paging.  This tutorial may help: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx