# Creating 'Browse user' page

Tags: php, mysql, css, foreach, foreach-loop-container

I have a table for users already created so for example I will run a query which will `SELECT * FROM users WHERE accType='1'` and I am looking to run a `foreach` loop on the results and put each result into this element

```
<div class="title-desc-wrap col-xs-12 col-md-8">
<div class="title-wrap "><h4><a href="LINK TO USERS PROFILE">User Name</a></h4></div> 
<div class="excerpt-wrap">PROFILE PICTURE</div>
</div>
```

I want to restrict the page to only show 8 users on each page. How would I go about structuring this `foreach` loop in PHP?

Comment: The first part can be answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848905/loop-through-database-and-show-in-table  as for the pagination maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742378/php-database-table-loop-display-only-15-rows-at-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366413/create-pagination-using-while-loop

Comment: Just putting this out there `accType='1'` should be `accType=1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure on `foreach` but for a `for` loop, if you are placing the results into an array, you could;

```
<?php
for($count = 0; $count < 8; $count++) {
$holder = $array_name['$count'];
echo "<a href=LINK TO USERS PROFILE>". $holder['userName'] ."</a>";
echo "<div class=excerpt-wrap>". $holder['ProfilePic'] ."</div>";
}
```

then for the next page;

```
<?php
for($count = 8; $count < 16; $count++) {
$holder = $array_name['$count'];
echo "<a href=LINK TO USERS PROFILE>". $holder['userName'] ."</a>";
echo "<div class=excerpt-wrap>". $holder['ProfilePic'] ."</div>";
}
```

and so on, bit basic but it should work.